# Ngif attribute Angular?

Tags: angular

I have tried to apply attribute if variable `multiple` is true:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="reglamentControl"  [attr.miltiple]="multiple ? true : null">
```

No working, how to do that in Angular?

Comment: "miltiple" typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **mat-select** as below.

```
<mat-select [formControl]="reglamentControl"  [multiple]="multiple">
```

Comment: Does not work, in tempate I see that variable is true: `        {{ multiple }}`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple is input property of mat-select so you can try like this.

```
<mat-select [formControl]="reglamentControl"  [multiple]="multiple">
```

Answer (score 0):

You used attr.miltiple instead of multiple

```
<mat-select [formControl]="reglamentControl"  [multiple]="multiple ? true : null">
```

I think it's more clear to use multiple directly instead of the ternary operator :

```
<mat-select [formControl]="reglamentControl"  [multiple]="multiple">
```

You can read the documentation for more information: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection